# NSOperationQueue: Can't add UIBarButtonItem in the Toolbar on Main Thread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, uiviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, nsoperationqueue

In my UIViewController I want to add a UIBarButtonItem in the Toolbar, but the new Button doesn't appear. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (void)doLogin:(NSString *)name password:(NSString *)password {
 // 1.: start the Thread:
 NSInvocationOperation *invOperation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(backgroundTaskLogin:) object:request];
 [self.opQueue addOperation:invOperation];
}

- (void)backgroundTaskLogin:(NSString *)request2 {
 // 2.: jump back in the Main Thread in show a cancel button in den toolbar:
 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showCancelButton) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void)showCancelButton {
 // 3.: add a new Cancel-Button in the Toolbar:
 UIBarButtonItem *tempButtonCancel = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelLogin)];
 NSMutableArray *myButtons = (NSMutableArray *)self.toolbarItems;
 NSLog(@"Count buttons: %d", [self.toolbarItems count]); // DEBUGGER: 2

 [myButtons addObject:tempButtonCancel];
 [tempButtonCancel release];

 NSLog(@"Count buttons: %d", [self.toolbarItems count]); // DEBUGGER: 3

 // PROBLEM: I don't see the new Toolbar-Button :-(
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't rely on `self.toolbarItems` being a mutable array. It may be one in your case if you assigned a mutable array to that property before but you can't expect the view controller to notice a change in a property if you don't use the documented interface.

Create a new array and use the setter to assign it to `toolbarItems`:

```
NSMutableArray *newToolbarItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.toolbarItems];
[newToolbarItems addObject:tempButtonCancel];
self.toolbarItems = newToolbarItems;
```

Comment: In my case, I assigned a mutable array to "toolbarItems", but you're right, [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.toolbarItems] works.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The code in Ole's post will fix your bug, but not for the reason he suggests (since it appears that you *are* successfully adding an item to the array, even if that shouldn't be mutable most of the time). You have to call `setToolbarItems:` after duplicating and modifying the items array because the UIToolbar does not detect that changes have been made to it's array otherwise.

You can also use `setToolbarItems:animated:` to fade things in nicely ;-)

Comment: Good clarification, Ben. That's what I meant with "you can't expect the view controller to notice a change in a property if you don't use the documented interface", though.

Comment: It's not because toolbarItems is mutable that it should use it as a mutable array if it's not declared mutable in the header. This could break in any iOS release.

Comment: [self setToolbarItems: myButtons animated:YES] works too, in combination with Ole's hint, thank you!